# Where is textBaseline in KineticJS?

Tags: kineticjs

I cannot find a tutorial or documentation showing how to change canvas's textBaseline property in KineticJS.  If you look [in the Kinetic.Text documentation](http://kineticjs.com/docs/Kinetic.Text.html) you won't find any mention of "base.." anything, and the [Kinetic Text tutorial](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-kineticjs-text-tutorial/) does not demonstrate its use either.  Did textBaseline make it into KineticJS?

I did a [jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/GeekStocks/8Rey2/) showing how textBaseline works on a raw canvas element, but I cannot figure out the property for doing the same thing in KineticJS.  I know the documentation is rough for KineticJS; perhaps a property is there but just not mentioned?

NO - adjusting the Y coordinate is not an option due to scaling issues.  Let's head that silliness off at the pass...

The following code should be placed using a bottom baseline, but as you can see in the fiddle, it uses "top".

```
  var text_b = new Kinetic.Text({
    x: 25,
    y: 100.5,
    text: 'Bottom',
    fontSize: 18,
    fontFamily: 'Verdana',
    fill: 'black'
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there is a KineticJS solution for `textBaseline` at the moment.

You'll have to use the `offset` method or property instead.

- [Kinetic.Shape#getOffset](http://kineticjs.com/docs/Kinetic.Shape.html#getOffset)
- [Kinetic.Shape#getOffsetX](http://kineticjs.com/docs/Kinetic.Shape.html#getOffsetX)
- [Kinetic.Shape#getOffsetY](http://kineticjs.com/docs/Kinetic.Shape.html#getOffsetY)
- [Kinetic.Shape#setOffset](http://kineticjs.com/docs/Kinetic.Shape.html#setOffset)
- [Kinetic.Shape#setOffsetX](http://kineticjs.com/docs/Kinetic.Shape.html#setOffsetY)
- [Kinetic.Shape#setOffsetY](http://kineticjs.com/docs/Kinetic.Shape.html#setOffsetY)

For example setting the `offset` property:

```
  var text_b = new Kinetic.Text({
    x: 25,
    y: 100.5,
    text: 'Bottom',
    fontSize: 18,
    fontFamily: 'Verdana',
    fill: 'black',
    offset: [0, 18] //Offset by full font-size
  });

  var text_m = new Kinetic.Text({
    x: 175,
    y: 100.5,
    text: 'Middle',
    fontSize: 18,
    fontFamily: 'Verdana',
    fill: 'black',
    offset: [0, 9] //Offset by half of font-size
  });

  var text_t = new Kinetic.Text({
    x: 300,
    y: 100.5,
    text: 'Top',
    fontSize: 18,
    fontFamily: 'Verdana',
    fill: 'black' //No offset, as you said the default was top alignment
  });
```

In the example above I am hard-coding the offset + font-size but you can easily set these values dynamically depending on your set of fonts and font-sizes.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/projeqht/A9BQc/) Note in my JSFiddle, I set the stage scale to **0.5**

Comment: Well that's a bummer, but +1 to you for showing not only a less hokey way of alignment (offset vs Y coordinate), but also proving that it scales in your fiddle.  Thanks!