# Vertical text alignment in Firefox differs from other browsers in KineticJS

Tags: firefox, html5-canvas, kineticjs, vertical-alignment

The vertical alignment of text seems to be different in different browsers when working with KineticJS. I created two JSFiddles that illustrate the problem: In the first, the text is rendered to a raw HTML5 canvas without the use of KineticJS (see [Raw HTML5 Example](http://jsfiddle.net/36Ya7/2/)). In this case, the text is aligned the same way in Chrome and FF. Here's the JS-code for raw HTML5 canvas:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

xOrigin = 10;
context.beginPath();
context.rect(xOrigin, 90, 107, 12);
context.fillStyle = 'yellow';
context.fill();
context.lineWidth = 2;
context.strokeStyle = 'black';
context.stroke();      

context.font = '11px Calibri';
context.fillStyle = 'black';
context.fillText('Hello World! Calibri', xOrigin + 9, 100);      

xOrigin = 141;
context.beginPath();
context.rect(xOrigin, 90, 103, 12);
context.fillStyle = 'cyan';
context.fill();
context.lineWidth = 2;
context.strokeStyle = 'black';
context.stroke();      

context.font = '11px Arial';
context.fillStyle = 'black';
context.fillText('Hello World! Arial', xOrigin + 9, 100);
```

However, when KineticJS is used, the text in Arial is placed one pixel higher in FF than in Chrome  (see [KineticJS Example](http://jsfiddle.net/96DQp/2/)). Here's the code for the KineticJS example:

```
  var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: 'container',
    width: 578,
    height: 200
  });

  var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

  var xOrigin = 10;

  var rect = new Kinetic.Rect({
    x: xOrigin,
    y: 90,
    width: 107,
    height: 12,
    fill: 'yellow',
    stroke: 'black',
    strokeWidth: 2
  });

  var simpleText = new Kinetic.Text({
    x: xOrigin + 9,
    y: 90,
    text: 'Hello World! Calibri',
    fontSize: 11,
    fontFamily: 'Calibri',
    fill: 'black'
  });

  layer.add(rect);
  layer.add(simpleText);

  xOrigin = 141
  var rect = new Kinetic.Rect({
    x: xOrigin,
    y: 90,
    width: 103,
    height: 12,
    fill: 'cyan',
    stroke: 'black',
    strokeWidth: 2
  });

  var simpleText = new Kinetic.Text({
    x: xOrigin + 9,
    y: 90,
    text: 'Hello World! Arial',
    fontSize: 11,
    fontFamily: 'Arial',
    fill: 'black'
  });

  layer.add(rect);
  layer.add(simpleText);


  stage.add(layer);
```

Is there a way to render text consistently across FF and Chrome with KineticJS? Unfortunately, there seems to be no text-baseline property in KineticJS ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18905564/where-is-textbaseline-in-kineticjs)). And why is it rendered correctly when working on the raw HTML5 canvas? Is this a KineticJS bug or did I miss something?